# ElasticSearch Nest Create Fields Object

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Looking at the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/source-filtering-usage.html) we should be able to create a new source filter like so

```
new SearchRequest<Project>
{
    Source = new SourceFilter
    {
        Include = Fields<Project>(p => p.Name, prop => prop.StartedOn)
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that `Fields` isn't typed and doesn't have a constructor.

How do I go about making a `Fields` for use in sourceFilters, queries etc?

Comment: Which version of NEST do you use?

Comment: @Rob I've got the latest off Nuget 2.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find `Fields<>` method in class `Infer`, so change example code to

```
new SearchRequest<Project>
{
    Source = new SourceFilter
    {
        Include = Infer.Fields<Project>(p => p.Name, prop => prop.StartedOn)
    }
}
```

Also you can import this static class in your cs file with `using static Nest.Infer;`, so you will be able to use this example as it is.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Field Inference documentation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/field-inference.html